# Hello World Android App Emulator not running

Tags: android, emulation

Hi guys I am trying to get a basic emulator running to display Hello World but the emulator appears but the phone never switches on. Please help me.

```
 D:\Installed_Softwares\AndroidSDK\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_24_2
    ERROR: resizing partition e2fsck failed with exit code 9
    emulator: WARNING: userdata partition is resized from 513 M to 800 M
    RegGetValueW failed 2 The system cannot find the file specified.
    RegGetValueW failed 2 The system cannot find the file specified.
    RegGetValueW failed 2 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Hax is enabled
    Hax ram_size 0x60000000
    HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
    emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
    emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
```

Will be glad to provide more information as needed.

Comment: Which CPU do you have?

Comment: I've got an Intel Core i5 2500K with virtualization enabled in the bios and HAXM installed. So that's not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, you have to resize (downgrade) the RAM of your emulator uses. 
Also, try to use an older version of the Android, like 4.2 or 4.4.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the partition issue on Windows:

Install [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe) and run the e2fsck cmd

```
# Navigate to AVD and change the API level of the folder
cd C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_16.avd
e2fsck -f userdata-qemu.img
```